# How to get ResourceResolver in a background thread?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling, jcr

I'm working on a solution in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) that receives an HTTP request containing a URL to a file, which I want to download and store in the JCR.

So, I have a servlet that receives the request. It spawns a thread so that I can do the download in the background, and then redirects to a confirmation page. This allows me to send the user on their way without waiting while I try to download the file.

I can download the file just fine, but I'm having trouble getting a usable ResourceResolver to store the file in the JCR from my thread.

At first, I simply referenced the request's ResourceResolver in the background thread:

**Servlet:**

```
public void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    signingProvider.getDocFromService(params, request.getResourceResolver());
    response.sendRedirect(confirmationPage);
}
```

**And in the provider class:**

```
public void getDocFromService(Map<String, String> params, ResourceResolver resolver) {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Session session = null;
            if (resolver != null) { 
                session = resolver.adaptTo(Session.class); 
                Node root = session.getRootNode();
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that didn't work. After reading up on resolvers vs threads, I thought I would be better off creating a new Resolver instance, so I tried to inject a ResourceResolverFactory:

**Servlet:**

```
signingProvider.getDocFromService(params);
```

**Provider:**

```
public void getDocFromService(Map<String, String> params) {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Reference
        private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

        // security hole, fix later
        ResourceResolver resolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
        Session session = null;
        if (resolver != null) {
            session = resolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
            Node root = session.getRootNode();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

but the ResourceResolverFactory is null, so I crash when asking it for a resolver. Apparently, no factory is getting injected into the `@Reference`

I would really rather not do the work on the main thread; after I download the file I'm going to turn around and read it from the JCR and copy it elsewhere. Both of these operations could be slow or fail. I have a copy of the file at the original URL, so the end-user needn't care if my download/uploads had trouble. I just want to send them a confirmation so they can get on with business.

Any advice on how to get a ResourceResolver in a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: @daniil-stelmakh brings a good point in his answer, sling jobs are much better suited for your purpose, to add to his answer, here is a sling tutorial that demonstrates sling jobs: https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/how-to-manage-events-in-sling.html

**To answer your question directly:**

The issue, really is the placement of `@Reference` annotation.
That annotation is handled by [Maven SCR Plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html) and it should be placed on a private member of a '@Component' annotated class.

Basically move your `ResourceResolverFactory` declaration to become a private member of your class, not the Thread.

```
@Component(
    label = "sample service",
    description = "sample service"
)
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

    public void getDocFromService(Map<String, String> params) {
        new Thread( new Runnable() {

           // security hole, fix later
           ResourceResolver resolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
           Session session = null;
           if (resolver != null) {
               session = resolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
               Node root = session.getRootNode();
               ...
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that the ResourceResolverFactory isn't getting injected, and is null, and therefore I get a NPE when trying to call resourceResolverFactory.get<anything>

Comment: working on this and one other approach, but almost time to leave for the holiday weekend, so will probably pick it up Tuesday. I'll update and let you know what works. Thanks for the help, very much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why, but the `@Reference` is now working -- it injects the factory, and now even the new thread gets the ResourceResolverFactory.

Comment: getAdministrativeResourceResolver is deprecated. You might want to use getServiceResourceResolver instead.

Answer (score 2):

For things like post\background processing you can use Sling Jobs. Please refer to the [documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html) to find out some details.

Comment: This is a better idea that creating threads. But you should have either added a code example or make this a comment. This is not really an answer for the question. Just a comment. (I did not down vote this answer)

Comment: Do we have such a rule in this game? :) I think the guy is capable of doing it by himself using code examples in the official documentation. Not a rocket science...

Comment: @DaniilStelmakh Thanks, this is a great suggestion -- and a reminder that it's often better to state the problem I'm trying to solve rather than the solution that' giving me trouble. Since it was already built and is now working, I'm going with my thread solution for now but will look at converting it to a Sling Job shortly. And you're right -- a link to the docs is sufficient to get me started.